# Search database with servlet and jquery

Tags: java, jquery, database, search, servlets

I am currently working on cinema project, I am stuck on search movies from database.
So, I have table of movies on my main page

```
<div id="moviesTable">

        <div class="col-md-2 text-center" id="moviesSearchBox">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="searchOptions">
                <select id="searchOptionsBox" name="searchOptionsBox" class="browser-default custom-select">
                    <option value="title">Title</option>
                    <option value="distributor">Distributor</option>
                    <option value="originCountry">Origin country</option>
                    <option value="yearOfProduction">Year of production</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="searchMovieInput">
                <input id="searchMovieInputBox" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div id="searchMovieBtnBox">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="searchMovieBtn">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <table id="moviesTable1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Distributor</th>
                    <th>Origin country</th>
                    <th>Year of production</th>
                </tr>       
            </thead>
            <tbody id="moviesTbody">

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

as you can see, I have select with options and one input for search, I want user to type in input, select one option and get desired results (I am using datatable, but need to implement custom search)

This is my MovieDAO, which I use to communicate with database.
By the way, I have method getAll in MovieDAO, and I'm able to get all movies and populate datatable with them.

```
public static List<Movie> searchMovies(String title, String distributor, String originCountry, Integer yearOfProduction) {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE";

        if (title != null && title !="") {
            query += " title LIKE ?";
        }
        if (distributor != null && distributor !="") {
            query += " distributor LIKE ?";
        }
        if (originCountry != null && originCountry !="") {
            query += " origincountry LIKE ?";
        }
        if (yearOfProduction != null && yearOfProduction !=0) {
            query += " yearofproduction = ?";
        }

        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            int index = 1;

            if (title != null && title !="") {
                ps.setString(index++, title);
            }
            if (distributor != null && distributor !="") {
                ps.setString(index++, distributor);
            }
            if (originCountry != null && originCountry !="") {
                ps.setString(index++, originCountry);
            }
            if (yearOfProduction != null) {
                ps.setInt(index++, yearOfProduction);
            }

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                index = 1;
                int id = rs.getInt(index++);
                String title_rs = rs.getString(index++);
                String duration = rs.getString(index++);
                String distributor_rs = rs.getString(index++);
                String originCountry_rs = rs.getString(index++);
                int yearOfProduction_rs = rs.getInt(index++);


                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setId(id);
                movie.setTitle(title_rs);
                movie.setDuration(duration);
                movie.setDistributor(distributor_rs);
                movie.setOriginCountry(originCountry_rs);
                movie.setYearOfProduction(yearOfProduction_rs);

                movies.add(movie);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SQL query error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {ps.close();} catch (Exception ex1) {ex1.printStackTrace();}
            try {rs.close();} catch (Exception ex1) {ex1.printStackTrace();}
        }

        return movies;
    }
```

SearchMoviesServlet

```
public class SearchMoviesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String searchOptionBox = request.getParameter("searchOptionBox");
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String distributor = request.getParameter("distributor");
        String originCountry = request.getParameter("originCountry");
        Integer yearOfProduction = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("yearOfProduction"));

        List<Movie> movies = MovieDAO.searchMovies(title, distributor, originCountry, yearOfProduction);
        if(searchOptionBox != null) {
            switch(searchOptionBox) {
                case "title":
                    Collections.sort(movies, Movie.titleComparator);
                    break;
                case "distributor":
                    Collections.sort(movies, Movie.distributorComparator);
                    break;
                case "originCountry":
                    Collections.sort(movies, Movie.originCountryComparator);
                    break;
                case "yearOfProduction":
                    Collections.sort(movies, Movie.yearOfProductionComparator);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }   
        }

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("movies", movies);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonData = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        System.out.println(jsonData);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(jsonData);

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

jquery script

```
searchMovies : function() {
            $('#moviesTable1').dataTable().fnClearTable();
            $.get('SearchMoviesServlet?searchOptionBox=' + $("searchOptionBox option:selected").val() + '&title='
                    + $("#title").val() + "&distributor=" + $("#distributor").val() + "&originCountry="
                    + $("#originCountry").val() + "&yearOfProduction=" + $("#yearOfProduction").val(), function(data){
                for(m in data.movies) {
                    $('#moviesTable1').dataTable().fnAddData ([
                        data.movies[m].title,
                        data.movies[m].duration,
                        data.movies[m].distributor,
                        data.movies[m].originCountry,
                        data.movies[m].yearOfProduction 
                        ]);
                }
            });


        }
```

It's clear to me that something is wrong in $get(), but I can't think through this and I'm stuck, any help is kindly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you open the Developer tools of the browser and see what exception you are getting on the page ?

Comment: I can only see error in eclipse console: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet SearchMoviesServlet threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined", but I don't know how to include value from input into this whole thing

Comment: Create that query first in the variable so that you can write the output in console for debugging and then only use in $.get